# Gui button not working

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm new here so sorry if it's a little hard to understand. Basically my problem is that I have to make a GUI Hangman game and I'm currently trying to get the guess button working but it doesn't seem that it wants to.

```js
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.MatteBorder;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Hangman2 {

  static final int maxguess = 8;
  static final int maxletter = 'z' - 'a' + 1;
  private JFrame frame;
  private JTextField textField;
  public int guess;

  /**
   * Launch the application.
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        try {
          Hangman2 window = new Hangman2();
          window.frame.setVisible(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   * Create the application.
   */
  public Hangman2() {
    initialize();
  }

  /**
   * Initialize the contents of the frame.
   */
  private void initialize() {

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 450, 206);
    panel.setBorder(new MatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, (Color) new Color(0, 0, 0)));
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(10, 211, 113, 26);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    JButton btnGuess = new JButton("Guess");
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnGuess);
    btnGuess.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        guess++;
      }
    });
    btnGuess.setBounds(6, 243, 125, 29);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnGuess);

    int guesses = (guess);

    JLabel lblNumberOfGuesses = new JLabel("Number of guesses:" + guesses);
    lblNumberOfGuesses.setBounds(135, 216, 155, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNumberOfGuesses);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error output in the console? What should  happen when you click the button?

Comment: what's wrong with the button?..Can you throw some light on what is not happening??

Comment: Why are you adding the button to the frame multiple times???

Comment: Basically what's happening is every time I click the Guess button it should increase by 1 until the game is lost. I've tried a variety of ways and none seem to add.

Comment: [Don't use null layout, A simple one to start with BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of your `JLabel` is **only set once**, in your `initialize` method.

Do this in your `actionPerformed` method, after incrementing guess :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        guess++;
        lblNumberOfGuesses.setText("Number of guesses:" + guess);
      }
```

Also, declare your JLabel **before** declaring the ActionListener, or you will have an error, since lblNumberOfGuesses will be unknown at this step.

Comment: Thank you Berger. I'm still really new with java so just needed a little help. have a great day.